# K9 web protection, trying to delete it

Tags: windows-10

Is there any simple way of deleting K9 Web Protection without the admin password? I admit my parents have installed this on my PC, but I think I'm old enough to not have it installed on my laptop.

Comment: Not quite an answer. But maybe talking to your parents about this might be a good idea.

Comment: Are you trying to bypass parental control feature from K9 ? No ? What do you want to achieve by uninstalling K9 ? Download malware :D If you are trying to solve a problem, explain the problem to your parents or to SuperUser. Either will help

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there any way of deleting K9 Web Protection without the admin password?

K9 specifically warns you not to even try (bad things will happen - you will lose all internet access).

You should have a discussion with your parents as to whether removing it is suitable for you.

---

#### K9 Uninstall Instructions (Windows)

> DO NOT ATTEMPT TO UNINSTALL K9 WITHOUT A PASSWORD.
>
> By design, K9 will block all internet access should one attempt to uninstall K9 without using a password.
>
> Attempts to modify K9 at the registry level will have the same effect.

Source [K9 Uninstall Instructions (Windows)](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/support/kb/K9146.html)